# ASP.net multiple select always returns 0 selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, razor, multi-select

So i'm trying to build a User multi-select in order to get the participants to a project. This is my code:

```
  <form asp-page-handler="ProjectModalPartial">
                @*numele metodei*@
                <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectName">Title</label>
                    <input asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectName" class="form-control" placeholder="MyProject1" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectDescription">Description</label>
                    <textarea asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectDescription" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="This is my first project"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label asp-for="ProjectsModel.MultiValues">Project participants</label>
                    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control chosen_participants" id="listbox1" asp-for="ProjectsModel.MultiValues" asp-items="@Model.Items" style="width: 470px;">
                     
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectsModel.MultiValues" class="text-danger"></span>

                </div>
            </form>
```

The page:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ProjectsList(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Project> ProjectList { get; private set; } = new List<Project>();
    [BindProperty]
    public ProjectsModel ProjectsModel { get; set; }
    public List<User> UserList { get; private set; } = new List<User>();

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
    = new List<SelectListItem>();
    public void OnGet()
    {

        ProjectList =  _context.Projects.ToList();
        Items = (from usr in this._context.Users
                 select new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Text = usr.Email.ToString(),
                     Value = usr.Id.ToString()
                 }).ToList();


    }

    public IActionResult OnPostProjectModalPartial()
    {
        Items = (from usr in this._context.Users
                 select new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Text = usr.Email.ToString(),
                     Value = usr.Id.ToString()
                 }).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var project = new Project
            {
                ProjectName = ProjectsModel.ProjectName,
                ProjectDescription = ProjectsModel.ProjectDescription,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                Active = true,
                ProjectCreatorId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value

            };
            _context.Projects.Add(project);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var person in Items)
            {
                _context.ProjectParticipants.Add(new ProjectParticipant
                {
                    ProjectId = project.Id,
                    UserId = person.Value
                });


            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

And the model:

```
   public class ProjectsModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public string ProjectCreatorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select atleast one participant")]
    public List<User> ProjectParticipants { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> MultiValues { get; set; }


}
```

However, when i put a breakpoint inside the foreachloop of OnPostProjectModalPartial i can see the list is populated with all the users but none of them is selected. What am i doing wrong?
Do i need some jquery script to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need indicate the property of your model associated to the selected option:

```
<select multiple="multiple" 
   class="form-control chosen_participants" 
   id="listbox1" 
   asp-for="UserId" // <-- This property
   asp-items="@Model.Items" 
   style="width: 470px;">
```

And add UserId property to your class:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Then, in the post, your model UserId has the selected user id and you can do a query to get all info that you need about that user.

NOTE: In your current OnPostProjectModalPartial, you are making a query in your database but without any kind of selection info getted from the post.

Comment: I'm sorry i had made some tries and forgot do add it back, it used to be asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectParticipants.... and ProjectParticipants is List<User>. It succesfully saves to the database but all the users instead of the selected ones

Comment: The select it to select one of the users. Is for that reason that you need a single property in which you receive the selected user.

Comment: ok, you were right. Instead of List<User> i used List<string> because it wouldn't work otherwise. And the reason it uploaded everything to the database is because i was looping trough all the existing Users not the selected ones

Comment: In this kind of situations, you know the list of users (it's the same in Get and Post actions). You don't need the list to be returned again from the form, you only need the selected user. In your post, you can iterate again in the users but now, knowing which has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some of the list of users selected you need to change your code, this piece of code in the page part

**ORIGINAL**

```
foreach (var person in Items)
{
    _context.ProjectParticipants.Add(new ProjectParticipant
    {
         ProjectId = project.Id,
         UserId = person.Value
     });
} //ORIGINAL
```

Into this:
Filtering only the **Model**.Iems selected

```
foreach (var person in model.Items.Where(item=> item.Selected))
{
    _context.ProjectParticipants.Add(new ProjectParticipant
    {
         ProjectId = project.Id,
         UserId = person.Value
     });
}
```

Also you did'nt need to go get the list again from database, you got it in the model

Comment: i'm not currently using anything of this kind, what is Active supposed to be?

Comment: @AndreiCuţă Sorry, I understood you want to show selected some items based on some value I'm editing my Answer to select (and save) only the selected items _in model_